# Darwin Streaming Server 6.0.3 won't send Closed Caption track

Tags: video

I can get the captions if I stream the Quicktime file through a link on my webserver, but if I try to stream the file via Darwin Streaming Server, the audio and video come through, but no captions.  The QT browser plugin has no option to enable captions so the caption track just has to come from the server. Or is it the plugin's fault? Any thoughts?  Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have no direct experience with DSS, but it appears, from what I could find online, that DSS does not support streaming a text track.  Rather, you seem to need to reference a non-streamed version that has text data.  I unfortunately couldn't find much more on what the one place I found mentioning that intended, so I'm sorry that it isn't very clear, but it was the best I could find.

Hopefully someone else has actual experience with DSS and can provide better guidance than I.